# How to read a string from a txt file and show it in a web pape? (SetTimeOut)

Tags: javascript

I have found this function that reads a value from a TXT file and displays it in a web page:

```
function PriceAc(s) 
{
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
    setTimeout(read, 30);
    function read(){
        jQuery.get('price.txt',function(data){
        $(s).html(data);});
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">PriceAc('#priceA')</script>
<div id="priceA"></div>
```

My question is: do I need the settimeout? Can I get rid of it?

---

PS: I have experience with other programming lang but now with JS.

Comment: Did you try getting rid of it?

Comment: The answer is simply: get rid of it and see if it still works as expected. If not, leave it in there.

Comment: @tymeJV-yes, it won't work without it.

Comment: @Altar: Well, there's your answer. (Assuming you tried just calling `read()` when you removed the `setTimeout()`)

Comment: To be clearer, what setTimeout() does is it invokes your read() function after a short delay (30). You could get rid of it and place a call to to read() manually.

Comment: @hbCyber-So... I don't really need the delay. Right?

Comment: @Altar -- Replace the `setTimeout` function with `read()`

Comment: Cool. My function has only 2 lines now. Thanks.

Comment: can anybody confirm that settimeout is not necessary in my case? I just got the script from internet. I don't know why they used it. But I think I am better without it.

Answer (score 0):

`My question is: do I need the settimeout? Can I get rid of it?`

Yes, you can get rid of the setTimeout, but you don't want to.

If you get rid of the setTimeout, then the code would look like this:

```
function PriceAc(s) 
{
   $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
   read();
   function read(){
     jQuery.get('price.txt',function(data){
     $(s).html(data);});
   }
}
```

or inline the read function like this:

```
function PriceAc(s) 
{
   $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
   jQuery.get('price.txt',function(data){
     $(s).html(data);
   });
}
```

BUT YOU DONT want to do this :)  The reason why is described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Especially check out the **Example: using a timeout** section

> Example: using a timeout
>
> You can use a timeout to prevent hanging your code forever while
>   waiting for a read to occur.

Comment: I am not an expert in web technologies BUT it seems that it is not CRITICAL to use the settimeout. From "You can use a timeout to prevent hanging your code forever while waiting for a read to occur" I understand that my web page will freeze ONLY if the script cannot read my TXT file. I think in 99.9999% of the cases the read will succeed. I don't see much reason for this to fail. So, no worry to much about it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Right, as far as getting the file read to occur, it is not critical.  Also, it may not be critical for the user that the file read occurs, and if the UI becomes unresponsive because of a synchronous request,  then the user's perception of your site/page/app may be critical to you.

Comment: Thanks. As there is a small chance for that error to occur I will keep the code without the timer. If it will ever occur, the will will probably fit the refresh button.